# Mongodb aggregation lookup to add field in each array with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections.

User:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d415"),
   "email":"br9@gmail.com",
   "username":"borhan"
}
```

Panel:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d417"),
   "name": "borhan",
   "users": [
      {
          "role": "admin",
          "joined": "2021-05-19T04:35:47.474Z",
          "status": "active",
          "_id": ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d418"),
          "user": ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d415")
      },
      {
          "role": "member",
          "joined": "2021-05-19T04:35:47.474Z",
          "status": "active",
          "_id": ObjectId("60a49600d4ba8b122899d41a"),
          "user": ObjectId("60a34e167958972d7ce6f966")
       }
    ],
}
```

Team:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("60a495e0d4ba8b122899d419"),
   "title":"New Teams",
   "users":[
      ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d415")
   ],
   "panel":ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d417")
}
```

I want to receive a output from querying Panel colllection just like this:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d417"),
   "name": "borhan",
   "users": [
      {
          "role": "admin",
          "joined": "2021-05-19T04:35:47.474Z",
          "status": "active",
          "_id": ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d418"),
          "user": ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d415"),
          "teams":[
             {
                 "_id":ObjectId("60a495e0d4ba8b122899d419"),
                 "title":"New Teams",
                 "users":[
                      ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d415")
                  ],
                 "panel":ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d417")
             }
          ]
      },
      {
          "role": "member",
          "joined": "2021-05-19T04:35:47.474Z",
          "status": "active",
          "_id": ObjectId("60a49600d4ba8b122899d41a"),
          "user": ObjectId("60a34e167958972d7ce6f966")
       }
    ],
}
```

I mean i want to add teams field (which is array of teams that user is existed on it) to each user in Panel collection

Here is my match query in mongoose to select specific panel:

```
panel_model.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {              
         users: {
            $elemMatch: {user: ObjectId("60a495cdd4ba8b122899d415"), role:"admin"}
         }
      }
   },
])
```

Is it possible to get my output with $lookup or $addFields aggregations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join all three collections,

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$lookup` there are two kind of lookups which help to join collections. First I used [Multiple-join-conditions-with--lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with--lookup), and I used standrad lookup to join `Users` and `Teams` collections.
- `$match` to match the user's id
- `$expr` - when you use `$match` inside lookup, u must use it.
- `$set` to add new fields
- `$group` to  we already destructed using `$unwind`. No we need to restructure it

here is the code

```
db.Panel.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$users" },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "User",
      "let": { uId: "$users.user" },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [ "$_id", "$$uId" ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "Team",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "users",
            "as": "teams"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "users.join"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "users.getFirstElem": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [ "$users.join", 0 ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "users.teams": "$users.getFirstElem.teams",
      "users.join": "$$REMOVE",
      "users.getFirstElem": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": { "$first": "name" },
      "users": { $push: "$users" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BFjTcc3gmyL)**

Note : Hope the panel and user collections are in 1-1 relationship. Otherwise let me know